# I can offer bounty to get right answer to my question

Tags: support

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: [How to make wireless router to connect to 2 P2P WiFi cameras in client mode at the same time](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/44148/how-to-make-wireless-router-to-connect-to-2-p2p-wifi-cameras-in-client-mode-at-t)

I really need your help to get the right answer.
I can offer bounty but please don't ask me to visit one another and one another forum to get no answer

Answer (score 3):

Part of your problem is that you don't give a good description or diagram of the network, the network device models and configurations, etc. We can help with enterprise network devices, but your hosts, servers, applications, and consumer-grade devices are all off-topic on network engineering.

Comment: Ok. I can connect to a single P2P WiFi IP camera wirelessly from app run on Android tablet via WiFi. But to connect to 2 P2P cameras at the same time over WiFi I need to have a WiFi router to share WiFi device/ interface/ channels among 2 WiFi devices to be connected.  Generally wireless router accepts connect requests from clients. Since P2P WiFi camera is a passive device (no buttons) I need to turn router into client mode to have router to connect wirelessly to 2 P2P WiFi IP cameras over WiFi. Nice manual https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html

Comment: "_Generally wireless router accepts connect requests from clients._" I have no idea where you get that. Routing has nothing to do with that. Clients and servers are application-layer (off-topic) concepts. Routing is a connectionless process, based only on the layer-3 addressing. Your problem seems to be obove OSI layer-4, which is off-topic on [networkengineering.se].

Comment: Ok. My question is WiFi topology related. A single WiFi interface connecting to 2 WiFi interfaces at the same time ( an old one-2-many topology solution). Since WiFi cameras are broadcast/ video streaming devices, so any connection my be router side invoked one-2-many in client mode.  BTW how to offer bounty to get question answered, problem solved >?

Comment: You cannot offer a bounty for a closed question. Your WAP (not router) connects to many hosts at the same time, this is standard. You seem to be confusing the layer-2 protocol (Wi-Fi) with the layer-3 protocols (IP and routing). Routers strip off any layer-2 frames to get to and route packets based on the IP address, so the router doesn't know the difference between Wi-Fi and ethernet (or any other layer-2 protocol). If you simply connect your WAP to the network, you can connect many different hosts to the network via Wi-Fi. How your host OSes connect to the network is off-topic.

Comment: @darius, doesn't your company have any network engineer or administrator (someone who understands networking) to manage your network?

Comment: I don't use WAP known from mobile telephony 10 years ago + GPRS. P2P WiFi IP camera is HD resolution standard. Guar app run on Android tablet can connect to a single P2P WiFi camera via a single WiFi interface. Installing router software, a single WiFi interface/hardware can be shared among a numer of P2P device (cameras in my case). Take it this way. 2 smartphones can connect to AP, Hotspot to share video to/via the Internet. You can view 2 video streams as 2 windows. Replace smartphones by P2P WiFi IP cameras. Replace AP Hotspot by WiFi Tablet

Comment: That is not a professionally managed network in a business environment. Businesses do not typically use P2P Wi-Fi because they need a consistent response that is easy to troubleshoot. Routers are used to route, switches are used to connect ethernet hosts, and WAPs are used to connect Wi-Fi hosts. Switches and WAPs can connect multiple hosts, but how the host OS connects to the network is off-topic here, and that seems to be the heart of your problem. [sf] handles networking for business which is off-topic on [networkengineering.se], and [su] handles networking for personal networks.

Comment: Ok, I need to install WiFi Access Point or Hotspot to share WiFi interface among a number of Peers first and router app to get each WiFi camera turned networked, to stream video to a single app

Comment: @rob in theory you are right but in practice wireless camera is a standard in business environment nowadays, the same for tablet, smartphone as monitoring, video watching device. So I do hope to find correct answer and solution this week.  BTW could you explain me why do you put so many efforts into discussing question asked, routing it via Stack Exchange Network sites, where no response can be expected over a long time (week, month or even a whole year) Stack Exchange turns black hole for questions asked.

Comment: The cameras, phones, tablets, etc. are network hosts. As I have pointed out several times, and as it says in the Help Center, hosts are off-topic on [networkengineering.se]. The purpose of this site was to separate the network questions from other types of questions on [sf] and [su] (where networks are also supported). If we allow off-topic questions (as defined by the community), then there is no point in having the separate SE site - we could have just kept using [sf] and [su]. The network engineers do not want to wade through a bunch of other questions to get to what interests them.

Comment: "The cameras, phones, tables, etc. are network hosts."

Comment: "The cameras, phones, tables, etc. are network hosts." hosts as video streamer but wifi/3G/LTE turns phone, tablet into client, connecting to wireless network. excellent manuals: http://www.aztcs.org/meeting_notes/winhardsig/WiFi-peer-to-peer/peer-to-peer-win.pdf  and http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/documentation  BTW Stack Exchange Network should employ AI to route questions automagically among SE sites since asking question one expects to get answer. But what is received is a nice chat with Ron about How to ask a correct question at the right place ;) thank you. How to offer bounty ?

Comment: See: _[What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)_

Comment: My last comment lost. Since I don't have points to share I would prefer to offer pocket money for the right answer. Not sure why did you remove Coffee&Powwer

Comment: I didn't remove anything, and the SE model dos not include any type of rewards, other than reputation.

Comment: Ron and others. My question is simple and really clear, so I am surprised not to get correct answer within hours. What I read are hard answers to easy question.

Comment: @darius It may be "simple and clear" in your mind, but it is anything but clear. In any case **it is off topic here so no one will provide you an answer here** either quickly or in the long term. Ask where it is on topic and you way get a quick answer. This is not that place.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do isn't a question about networking. Just because something uses networking doesn't make it a networking question.

Wi-Fi Direct allows two client devices to connect to each other directly and transfer data without the use of any intermediary devices. Wi-Fi Direct does not support connecting multiple clients to multiple other clients through an intermediary device. This is a third party development.

Your question is really about how to configure an application/service that someone developed to allow you believe will do what you want. Questions about the support of applications/services that are not directly related to the network are simply not on topic on this site.

Ron has let you know this a number of times as nicely as he can and I do understand it can be frustrating at times to find the right place to ask a question, but this is not it. You need to take your question elsewhere if you hope to get an answer as this community is not suited for your question.

If you do try to post on another SE site, again as Ron stated, you will need to give more information about what you are doing if anyone has a hope of helping you. Models of the devices, what the software is you are trying to use, etc.

Comment: again,  hard answers to easy question. BTW P2P standard has nothing to do with WiFi Direct standard as I have pointed out earlier, proving links for Android developers' website and other sites. None application has anything to do with WiFi wireless router as client to multi-peers topology described as the problem is of general nature, so do hope to solve it with support provided by CISCO and others

Comment: @darius WiFI P2P isn't a standard itself and is the basis of WiFI Direct which has superseded it. Android still uses the name P2P because they started with it, but it is now WiFi Direct compliant. The last part of your comment establishes my point that this isn't a network issue, rather an application/service issue. You aren't looking for network help instead general help on using your software, which is off topic on this site.

Answer (score 3):

The answers from @YLearn and @RonMaupin already address the off-topic part, so I'd like to answer the bounty part.

In my experience of this site, good questions do receive answers, without the need of a bounty.
When they do not receive an answer, it is because nobody present at the time has a good answer to propose.

A bounty is more likely to attract poor answers, as it will attract people looking for reputation (which IMHO is not the good way to look at a S.E. site), and push them to post an answer, even when they don't have a **good** one.

To be fair there's one good side of the bounty system, it is to give more visibility to the question, passed the first hours when the question is on the top of the list

But once again, N.E. has a very good rate of great answers on good questions. The fact is, the specific question discussed here is not a good question -for all reasons previously given- and a bounty will not change it into a good question.

Comment: +1 for "*The fact is, the specific question discussed here is not a good question -for all reasons previously given- and a bounty will not change it into a good question.*"